# ResNet50 and VGG16 for data with 2 channels

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, resnet, vgg-net

Is there any way that I can try to modify ResNet50 and VGG16 where my data(spectograms) is of the shape (64,256,2)?
I understand that I can take some layers out and modify them(output, dense) but I am not really sure for input channels.

Can anyone suggest a way to accommodate 2 channels in the models? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: you want combine both model or you want to use pretrained model + your model

Comment: I would like to modify the pretrained models (both of them separately) to fit my 2 channel data. @JaiMahesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a different number of channels in the input (and a different height and width), but in this case, you cannot use the pretrained imagenet weights. You have to train from scratch. You can create them as follows:

```
from tensorflow import keras # or just import keras

vggnet = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(input_shape=(64,256,2), include_top=False, weights=None)
```

Note the `weights=None` argument. It means initialize weights randomly. If you have number of channels set to `3`, you could use `weights='imagenet'`, but in your case, you have 2 channels, so it won't work and you have to set it to `None`. The `include_top=False` is there for you to add final classification layers with different categories yourself. You could also create `vgg19.VGG19` in the same way. For ResNet, you could similarly create it as follows:

```
resnet = keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(input_shape=(64, 256, 2), weights=None, include_top=False)
```

For other models and versions of vgg and resnet, please check [here](https://keras.io/applications/).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I made it work! Too bad I can't adapt the pretrained versions..